# Plagiarism detector software (local or online)

Tags: gratis, open-source, osx, plagiarism-detection

I want to detect plagiarism from a technical textbook (e-book). The book is a guide for a specific programming language.

**Task**: A document needs to be compared against the official documentation of the language and if possible, the blogs about the programming language on the internet.

So, the documents which needs to be compared against are the PDF e-book, and all websites, and the document to check is a PDF (.docx and .pages also available).

Answer (score 1):

This software will most probably not work for PDF or docx as such, you'd have to extract the ASCII-like text first. However, once you do, it's an excellent tool for computer forensics:

http://ssdeep.sourceforge.net/